# How to handle 2 this.state variable together in react native?

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

Want to access JSON data using 2 state variables. for example json contain

```
{
  "user1":
    {"age":32, 
     "role_name":"editor"
    },
  "user2":
    {"age":42,
     "role_name":"moderator"
    }
}
```

var1 contain "user1"
var2 contain "age" 
want to access something like

```
jsonobj.this.state.var1.this.state.var2
```

code that i tried

```
jsonobj.(this.state.var1).(this.state.var2)

jsonobj.{this.state.var1}.{this.state.var2}
```

but none of them worked

Comment: That's not how JS works. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: var1 and var2 have key element for getting json data

Comment: elaborate the problem properly. Please show what jsonobj has and what is var1 and var2 in your state.

Comment: Are you trying to get the item in the object based off two state values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `jsonobj[this.state.var1][this.state.var2]`

Comment: Then the value at that key path is undefined. This is basic JavaScript syntax.  See the "Accessing Object Properties" section of the following page: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp